# PC Will Not Boot

Tags: boot, fsck

I was using my PC, I clicked to close the Opera browser and then clicked on LibreOffice Calc.  After about 2 minutes Calc hadn't started so I clicked on the icon again. Once again after 3-4 minutes it still had not started, so I shut down the system using the on/off button as the on-screen controls were not working.

When I rebooted I just got the black screen below:

[image]

Comment: Your disk is failing.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The computer says that `/dev/sda5` has some inconsistency.

Run the command `fsck -a /dev/sda5` to fix it.